# Jquery get list of checkbox ids to send to mvc controller action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have multiple form with unique id and has same set of checkbox elements. I want to get the list of checkbox ids in an array using jQuery and send it to mvc action where the argument is of type IEnumberable.

I used the below code in jQuery to get the checked checkbox inside the form but not successful. Can anyone help me how to solve this?

```
        var test = $("#11form input[type='checkbox']:checked");
        alert(test.length);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = $("#11form input[type='checkbox']:checked");

var ids = test.map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).toArray();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wC9VS/6/)**

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately i didnt get ids. Even though one of the checkbox is checked, test.length is not showing any value.

Comment: The jsfiddle demo did not load, but the code in the example worked fine for me in I.E.9.  Thank you.